# NSCache evicting objects on setObjectForKey

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, nscache

NSCache is evicting objects everytime I set one! This is nuts.

Here is how I'm adding objects:

```
    [self.inMemoryCache setObject:@{@"data" : data, @"filePath" : filePath} forKey:filePath];
```

Here is my delegate method willEvictObject:

```
-(void)cache:(NSCache *)cache willEvictObject:(id)obj
{
    NSLog(@"evicted obj %@",[obj description]);
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSData *data = [obj objectForKey:@"data"];
        NSString *filePath = [obj objectForKey:@"filePath"];
        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
        NSArray *viewControllerNames = obj;
        [viewControllerNames writeToFile:[UINavigationController pathToData] atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

Every time I add object to the cache it evicts it. Really strange.

Any ideas? Here is how I'm allocating it:

```
    navigationController.inMemoryCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
    navigationController.inMemoryCache.delegate = navigationController;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? I'm having my own flavor of NSCache fun right now - different issue, but I'm curious and probing regarding its reliability.